# Laravel Forge and Custom VPS

Tags: php, laravel, forge

So I installed new Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Proliant gen9. Then I tried to provision new server and everything completed in terminal, but on Forge website there is loop on provisioning (stays on Performing Forge Nginx Maintenance.). What is wrong?

Comment: Have you installed 64bit version of Ubuntu? If yes, I think you should contact forge support about this. The only requirement mentioned by forge is Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

Comment: Yes I am using 64bit version. After some configuration I got Nginx performance maintaining loop (error: permission denied - (keyboard interactive).